# IEEE standard with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I'm using `biblatex` and tried to use the `ieee` style. The problem is that it doesn't seem to correctly use ieee-style at all. For instance when referencing something with more than 3 authors it should according to [this](https://elc.polyu.edu.hk/referencing/IEEE.pdf) document only mention the first author and et al. But instead it references 3 authors and then et al. Also in the bibliography/reference-section when it's more than 7 authors only the first author and et al should be used, but the package isn't doing that either. Is this package completely wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide test cases that show exactly what is going wrong. (The gold standard would be to provide them in the form of an MWE/MWEB: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). If you think that `biblatex-ieee` does not comply with IEEE requirements, you should report this as a bug at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues directly to the author.

Comment: I should say though that googling for IEEE style brings up several documents, not all with exactly the same details. The document you link does not appear to have been published by the IEEE: It appears to be some university's guidelines. Maybe those guidelines are based on older/outdated IEEE recommendations or contain some "house style" modifications to vanilla IEEE style.

Comment: The same thing appears in [this](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) document too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the more official looking guide you posted in the comments (IEEE Reference Guide, V11.12.2018, https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) suggests that the `maxnames` and `minnames` settings of `biblatex-ieee` are off.

The following settings appear to be closer to the requirements

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ieee,
  minnames=1,
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=6
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \textcite{aksin}
dolor \textcite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde [1] ipsum Aksın et al. [2] dolor Goossens et al. [3]//Ö. Aksın et al., “Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions,” J. Organomet. Chem., vol. 691, no. 13, pp. 3027–3036, 2006.]

**Please report deviations from the desired reference format to the package author.** For `biblatex-ieee` you can report issues via https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues. Consider including a few example entries that exhibit the incorrect behaviour and a reference to those bits of the style guidelines that are not correctly implemented.

Comment: The IEEE use a numeric style, so `maxcitenames` is at best a distraction

Comment: @JosephWright I believe it is appropriate sometimes to both use numbers and mention the authors. For example  "Brown [3] showed that..."

Comment: Thanks for the solution, much appreciated!

Comment: @Ferus Yes, but personally I'd write that out by hand (as then you get to choose the name - I'm from a subject area where you don't automatically pick the first author for these cases)

Comment: @JosephWright Makes sense then, but if you do use it automatically it's nice to have a tool that seamlessly follows the style instead of keeping track of all rules.